# Support for test program flow iteration

Tags: origen-sdk

I plan to iterate around many attributes of the $dut model and various test conditions in my test program.  I was testing out a very simple flow and am getting an error regarding duplicate test IDs.

```
Flow.create do |options|

  [:pmin, :pmax].each do |cond|
    bist :mbist, ip: :cpu, testmode: :hr, cond: cond, id: :hr
  end

end
```

Here is the error:

```
[ERROR]      64.198[0.193]   || Test ID hr_965EA18 is defined more than once in flow ws1:
[ERROR]      64.199[0.001]   ||   /users/user/origen/ppekit/program/components/_bist.rb:4
[ERROR]      64.199[0.000]   ||   /users/user/origen/ppekit/program/components/_bist.rb:4
```

I guess I would expect this to work but when I checked out the [test program generator docs](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/flows/) I didn't see an example of loops, only conditionals.  I do see the concept of [re-useable flow snippets](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/flows/#Re-usable_Flow_Snippets) but that seems to work best for a repeatable sequence of tests, versus just iterating ad-hoc.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Your code expands to this:

```
bist :mbist, ip: :cpu, testmode: :hr, cond: :pmin, id: :hr
bist :mbist, ip: :cpu, testmode: :hr, cond: :pmax, id: :hr
```

Which means you have two tests with the ID `:hr`, which is not allowed as IDs must be unique.

Either consider if you really need the ID, you probably don't unless you are referring to this test in [a conditional execution relationship with another test](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/flowapi/#Execution_Based_on_a_Previous_Test), or else update your code to generate unique IDs:

```
[:pmin, :pmax].each do |cond|
  bist :mbist, ip: :cpu, testmode: :hr, cond: cond, id: "hr_#{cond}"
end
```

Comment: OK then if I have 100 tests and I want to do a conditional branch if any of them failed, do I have to keep track of 100 IDs?

Comment: No, you can wrap them in a group and assign an ID to the group. The docs actually need to be updated with this info, but you can see an example in the code here: http://origen-sdk.org/origen/videos/5-create-program-flow/